# Separador de miles con javascript php o Jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Estoy intentando hacer un formato de moneda "peso" para mi input, en donde quiero que se formatee automáticamente al ingresar con separador de miles(".")
He probado con varios códigos y no funcionan

Comment: ¿Qué  intentó? ¿A qué códigos se refiere? añada el código a su pregunta ,empleando el enlace _editar._

Comment: $("#Valor").on({ 
"focus": function (event) {
$(event.target).select();
},
"keyup": function (event) {
$(event.target).val(function (index, value ) {
return value.replace(/\D/g, "")
 .replace(/([0-9])([0-9]{2})$/, '$1.$2')
 .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d)\.?)/g, ",");
 });
 }
});

Comment: function separador(Valor) {
      var nums = new Array();
      var simb = "."; 
      Valor = Valor.toString();
      Valor = Valor.replace(/\D/g, "");   
      nums = Valor.split(""); 
      var long = nums.length - 1; 
      var patron = 3;
      var prox = 2; 
      var res = "";
      
      while (long > prox) {
       nums.splice((long - prox),0,simb); 
       prox += patron;
      }
      
      for (var i = 0; i <= nums.length-1; i++) {
       res += nums[i]; 
      }
 
      return res;
      }

Answer (score 3):

Si lo que deseas es formatear el número mientras se escribe puedes agregar un evento `keyup` ya sea con jquery o javascript que este tome el valor y utilizando el método `Number.prototype.toLocaleString()` formatear el número y agregarlo al valor del input.

Ejemplo realizado con javascript:

```js
const number = document.querySelector('.number');

function formatNumber (n) {
 n = String(n).replace(/\D/g, "");
  return n === '' ? n : Number(n).toLocaleString();
}
number.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
 const element = e.target;
 const value = element.value;
  element.value = formatNumber(value);
});
```

```html
<input type="text" class="number">
```

Te dejo un [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Number/toLocaleString) con documentación sobre el método toLocaleString()

Comment: Este codigo me funciona perfect, el unico problema es que lo hace con todos los input text y no solo con uno de ellos que es el en q quiero q se muestre

Comment: (fixed) había añadido el evento keyup al document y no a la variable number. Ahora debería funcionar. También puedes usar el selector de jQuery y añadirle el evento keyup, algo así $('.number').keyup() y pasarle el callback.

Answer (score 2):

Yo uso el siguiente código en Javascript:

```
function formatNumber(num) {
    if (!num || num == 'NaN') return '-';
    if (num == 'Infinity') return '&#x221e;';
    num = num.toString().replace(/\$|\,/g, '');
    if (isNaN(num))
        num = "0";
    sign = (num == (num = Math.abs(num)));
    num = Math.floor(num * 100 + 0.50000000001);
    cents = num % 100;
    num = Math.floor(num / 100).toString();
    if (cents < 10)
        cents = "0" + cents;
    for (var i = 0; i < Math.floor((num.length - (1 + i)) / 3) ; i++)
        num = num.substring(0, num.length - (4 * i + 3)) + '.' + num.substring(num.length - (4 * i + 3));
    return (((sign) ? '' : '-') + num + ',' + cents);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Con PHP: 2 decimales separados por comas y miles por punto.

```
$pesos = number_format($cantidad, 2,',','.');
```

También tienes la función [money_format](http://php.net/manual/es/function.money-format.php), que es específica para moneda.