# Separadores de miles

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Tengo la siguiente estructura.

```js
function agregarDetalle(idarticulo,nombre)
  {
    var cantidad=1;
    var precio_compra=1;
    var precio_venta=1;
    if (idarticulo!="")
    {
        var subtotal=cantidad*precio_compra;
        var fila='<tr class="filas" id="fila'+cont+'">'+
        '<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="eliminarDetalle('+cont+')">X</button></td>'+
        '<td><input type="hidden" name="idarticulo[]" value="'+idarticulo+'">'+nombre+'</td>'+
        '<td><input type="number" name="cantidad[]" id="cantidad[]" value="'+cantidad+'"></td>'+
        '<td><input type="number" name="precio_compra[]" id="precio_compra[]" value="'+precio_compra+'"></td>'+
        '<td><input type="number" name="precio_venta[]" value="'+precio_venta+'"></td>'+
        '<td><span name="subtotal" id="subtotal'+cont+'">'+subtotal+'</span></td>'+
        '<td><button type="button" onclick="modificarSubototales()" class="btn btn-info"><i class="fa fa-refresh"></i></button></td>'+
        '</tr>';
        cont++;
        detalles=detalles+1;
        $('#detalles').append(fila);
        modificarSubototales();
    }
    else
    {
        alert("Error al ingresar el detalle, revisar los datos del artículo");
    }
  }
```

al cual necesito agregar separadores de miles a los input con id #precio_compra y #precio_venta

probe con los ejemplos :
[Separador de miles con javascript php o Jquery](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/82651/separador-de-miles-con-javascript-php-o-jquery) y [¿Como dar formato de número a todos los elementos?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/128303/como-dar-formato-de-n%C3%BAmero-a-todos-los-elementos)

pero ninguno me funciona.

Comment: ¿Cómo no te funcionan las soluciones de las preguntas que has enlazado? ¿Te dan algún error o muestran algún mensaje?

Comment: no da error y tampoco un mensaje, el código que compartí esta en archivo .js, si lo hiciera en .html funcionan a la perfección. se entiende ?

Comment: La pregunta no menciona el uso de PHP por lo que eliminé la etiqueta correspondiente. El código no es ejecutable por lo que eliminé Stack Snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si quieres aplicar un formato personalizado a los números no puedes utilizar el `type="number"`. De esta forma es el navegador el que controla el formato de introducción de los números.

Deberías cambiarlos por `type="text"` y después controlar por código que los valores introducidos por el usuario son correctos.

```js
var cont= 1;

function agregarDetalle(idarticulo,nombre)
{
  var cantidad = parseInt(Math.random() * 100);
  var precio_compra = Math.random() * 20;
  var precio_venta = Math.random() * 35;
  if (idarticulo!="")
  {
    var subtotal = cantidad * precio_compra;
    var fila='<tr class="filas" id="fila'+cont+'">'+
    '<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="eliminarDetalle('+cont+')">X</button></td>'+
    '<td><input type="hidden" name="idarticulo[]" value="'+idarticulo+'">'+nombre+'</td>'+
    '<td><input type="number" name="cantidad[]" id="cantidad[]" value="' + cantidad +'"></td>'+
    '<td><input type="text" name="precio_compra[]" id="precio_compra[]" value="'+precio_compra.toLocaleString() +'"></td>'+
    '<td><input type="text" name="precio_venta[]" value="'+precio_venta.toLocaleString()+'"></td>'+
    '<td><span name="subtotal" id="subtotal'+cont+'">'+subtotal.toLocaleString()+'</span></td>'+
    '<td><button type="button" onclick="modificarSubototales()" class="btn btn-info"><i class="fa fa-refresh"></i></button></td>'+
    '</tr>';
    cont++;
    detalles=detalles+1;
    $('#detalles').append(fila);
    //modificarSubototales();
  }
  else
  {
    alert("Error al ingresar el detalle, revisar los datos del artículo");
  }
}
  
$(function(){
  $('#agregar').click(function(){
    agregarDetalle('ID' + cont, 'Artículo ' + cont);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="detalles"></table>

<button id="agregar">Agregar</button>
```